# Ajax call from js to solr for spatial search

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, solr, geospatial

what am i doing wrong here? I am trying to access data from solr from js ajax calls which results in error. How to provide spatial data?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxx:20000/solr/cvcorelm0/select',
    data: {
        'wt':"json", 
        'q':"*:* AND doctype:1", 
        'fq':"{!geofilt}",
        'spatial':true,
        'pt':28.314744,84.778104,
        'd':100},
        'success': function(data) {
            console.log(data);        
        },
        'error':function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json.wrf'
    });
```

Please help

Comment: Note, the code misses a `}`.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed `}` at end for `data: {`, should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxx:20000/solr/cvcorelm0/select',
    data: {
        'wt':"json", 
        'q':"*:* AND doctype:1", 
        'fq':"{!geofilt}",
        'spatial':true,
        'pt':28.314744,84.778104,
        'd':100},
        'success': function(data) {
            console.log(data);        
        },
        'error':function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json.wrf'
    } // the missed } here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = 28.314744,84.778104;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxx:20000/solr/cvcorelm0/select',
    data: {
        'wt':"json", 
        'q':"*:* AND doctype:1", 
        'fq':"{!geofilt}",
        'spatial':true,
        'pt':temp,
        'd':100},                    //data { is closed here.
        'success': function(data) {
            console.log(data);        
        },
        'error':function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json.wrf'
    });
```

Worked when 28.314744,84.778104 is assigned to a variable and provided in data.